# How to check if Dart List contains certain object instance?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Dart `List<Book> bookList;` Somewhere in the code it has been filled with books.

How can I check if the bookList contains an instance of a `Book`?
I tried this

```
if(bookList.contains(Book))
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: any update for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is` to check the type of the List.

```
if (bookList is List<Book>) { 
    print("Yes");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, you annotated the type of your `bookList` with `List<Book>` meaning that any instance should be a `Book` or `null` when the list is not empy.

As many others pointed out already, the `is` is used to test if an object has a specified type. In your case that does not fully solve your problem. If your list contains `null`, the code

```
if (bookList is List<Book>) { 
    print("Yes");
}
```

will produce `Yes`. You have to check it like so:

```
class Book {
  String title;
  Book(this.title);
}

void main() {
  List<Book> bookList = [
    Book('foo'),
    null,
  ];

  if ((bookList?.length != 0 ?? false) && (!bookList?.contains(null) ?? false) && bookList is List<Book>) { 
    print("Yes");
  } else {
    print("No");
  }
}
```

to provide null-safety.

**EDIT** Updated my answer to be null safe towards `bookList` being `null`.

Check the docs:

- `is` test operator: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators
- null-safety: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 0):

You could test the following:

```
if (bookList.every((item) => item != null && item is Book)) {
   ...
}
```

If your bookList is by design a List, testing for nullity is enough:

```
if (bookList.every((item) => item != null)) {
  ...
}
```

If you want to prevent null elements inside the list, you should enforce it also when you add/update element to your list.